# Авторизация через vk

Tags: android, авторизация, java

Помогите. Хочу сделать авторизацию через vk, делаю по инструкции вот ссылка https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk
Выводить ошибку, в гугл как исправить ошибку не нашел?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: не импортирована библиотека в проект

Comment: библиотека подключёна вот рисунок http://s014.radikal.ru/i327/1404/1b/a2c74370975a.png

Comment: видимо, как то не правильно импортирована значит, раз не видит ее...

Comment: Вот снял видео как импортирую проект, подключаю библиотеку, но ошибка все еще есть
[url]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3tQ8s60HQ&feature=youtu.be[/url]

пробовал удалять папку gen, толку нет
http://i020.radikal.ru/1404/c3/c4517ae8f249.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у Вас не подключена библиотека
в ссылке которую Вы указали все написано

Подключение в Eclipse
1) В Package explorer нажмите правую кнопку мыши, затем Import. 
2) Выберите Android/Existing android code into workspace. 
3) Найдите папку с SDK, выберите vksdk library. 
4) Откройте Properties нового проекта vksdk library, далее Java build path, Add folder, и выберите java. 
5) В Properties Вашего приложения перейдите в Android, в секции library добавьте новую библиотеку vksdk library.